# Setup bridge network connection for windows guest hosted by VM Fusion

Tags: windows-10, window, vmware-fusion, wireless-bridge

I have windows 10 running as guest on a VM fusion service version 8.5.8.
The windows system has the latest VM tools installed.

To setup the connection i select auto detect on Bridge connections but windows doesn't detect the network.

I try several things:
- ipconfig /renew
- Reinstall the vm drivers.
- regenerate mac address for vm

Any pointers to investigate? Changing the connection should work seamless.

Answer (score 0):

Find out.
The problem was the router. 
The command `ip /renew` responded:

> An error occurred while renewing interface Ethernet0 : unable to
>   contact your DHCP server. Request has timed out.

When i disable Energy saving option on my wi-fi router, i was able to renew  configuration by dhcp (doing ip/renew again).