# Diagnosing an email bounce from a free Gmail business domain

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, gmail, office365, domain-name

I have an email address associated with one of Google's free business domains for my former employer, a nonprofit public interest research group. The organization went bankrupt about a decade time ago. I believe I was designated as an administrator at that time, as I was the "last man standing," so to speak. I continued to get considerable email via my address at this domain, as all my papers published during that era (on climate and energy policy, mainly) gave that domain for my email my address. I managed to set it up to forward that email to my current email account. This was over five years ago.

I recently had some reason to believe that emails sent to me via that address were not reaching me. In an effort to test this, I sent myself an email. I got back a bounce:

```
This site can’t be reached
Check if there is a typo in <CODE>.prod.protection.outlook.com.
If spelling is correct, try running Windows Network Diagnostics.
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN
```

I understand that the "prod.protection.outlook.com" message comes from the MS-Office 360 spam filter. My former employer did use Outlook, but all the machines on which it was installed vanished with the organization, and the associated email continued to work for many years. I now use Gmail exclusively. I have Office 2016 installed on my machine, but I have never used it -- I use LibreOffice, not MS-Office. So I am at a loss how I can be getting  a bounce message from outlook.

I reset (`flush release renew`) my DNS. The renew said:

```
An error occurred while renewing interface Wi-Fi: 
The operation was canceled by the user.
```

However, my wifi gives every other sign of functioning normally.

I am at best an only-slightly-super user, stuck with an administrator's duties by default. So I'd be very grateful for any advice you can offer on how best to proceed. My OS is Windows 10.

--andrewH

Comment: What client you use has little to do with the domain of your email if it was handled by Office 365.  “An error occurred while renewing interface Wi-Fi” - is an indication that you don’t have working dns server

Comment: [Here](https://superuser.com/questions/1259711/setup-bridge-network-connection-for-windows-guest-hosted-by-vm-fusion/1259716#1259716) is a similar situation

Comment: It seems to be more related to your Internet, have you tried to test on other client(such as your mobile or other PC)? And are there any errors when you run Windows Network Diagnostics? I have recently found an article that mentioned many suggestions about network troubleshooting:https://www.kapilarya.com/wifi-ethernet-doesnt-have-a-valid-ip-configuration-windows-10